# Generate sin/cos wave between two random points

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I want to create a vector of [x,y] points which will create sin or cos wave between two randomly points. I also want to be able to control the amplitude and the frequency of the generated way.
How can I do that? (python / matlab code will be perfect)

specific example:

```
pt_1 = [0,0]
pt_2 = [10,-10]
vector = generate_wavy_points(pt_1,pt_2)
```

No need to draw the points just creating vector which hold the points along the way between point_1 and point_2 (describing curvy line).

Comment: It is not completely clear what you ask. Do you want to choose two points on the plane and join them by a wavy line? Are you just asking for the code to draw that?

Comment: I have edited the question. No need to draw that just to create the vector of points which will create curvy line between point 1 and point 2.

Comment: The straight line $\vec{P}(t) = (x,y)$ along the two points can be written $\vec{P}(t) = \vec{P}_1 + (\vec{P}_2 - \vec{P}_1)t$ for $t$ going from $0$ to $1$. The wave height can be written $z(t) = A\sin(2\pi n t)$ where $A$ is the amplitude and $n$ is an integer denoting the frequency. You then have to plot the curve $(x(t),y(t),z(t))$ as $t$ goes from $t=0$ to $t=1$ to get a wave between the two points. Or do you want the wave to lie in the $(x,y)$ plane? Its still not very clear the way its written.

Comment: I want the wave to lie on the (x,y) plane. similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2092961/how-to-generate-a-sine-curve-between-two-points) but with the flexability to control the Amp as freq.

Comment: I think this question should be moved to stackoverflow or some other programming se site